# The entropy change of a closed system undergoing an adiabatic process is zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

I got this question for a quiz in class, and I believed that the entropy change can't be zero because for it to be zero, the process should be reversible and adiabatic. So since there was no option I marked none of the above. (See attached image)
But prof. marked it as wrong. So now, I am confused.[image: Quiz question]

Comment: Of course you are correct.  The process must also be reversible, and not just adiabatic.

Comment: What Chester wrote... For an irreversible process, $dS>T\delta Q$, so if the process is also adiabatic $dS>0$.

Answer (score -2):

The correct answer is zero. In adiabatic process energy is transferred to its surrounding only as work.